# termguicolors in vim makes everything black and white

Tags: vim

The idea is that by using `set termguicolors` in Vim, I should get the colorscheme (gruvbox) to look in my terminal (`st`, has true color support) exactly like in GVim. But all I get is white text on black background.

The part in vimrc which sets the colorscheme:

```
set background=dark
colorscheme gruvbox
set termguicolors
```

Comment: @yolenoyer yeah..i mistyped

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You might read `:h xterm-true-color`.

I'm using `st` as well, and indeed, setting `termguicolors` gave me black and white colors only.

But by following the advice in the help, I added the following:

```
let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
```

Then colors appeared again. Hope it can help.

Here is the whole excerpt from `:h xterm-true-color`:

> Vim supports using true colors in the terminal (taken from
> |highlight-guifg| and |highlight-guibg|), given that the terminal
> supports this. To make this work the 'termguicolors' option needs to
> be set. See https://gist.github.com/XVilka/8346728 for a list of
> terminals that support true colors.
>
> Sometimes setting 'termguicolors' is not enough and one has to set the
> |t_8f| and |t_8b| options explicitly. Default values of these options
> are "^[[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum" and "^[[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum" respectively,
> but it is only set when `$TERM` is `xterm`. Some terminals accept the
> same sequences, but with all semicolons replaced by colons (this is
> actually more compatible, but less widely supported):
>
> ```
>      let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38:2:%lu:%lu:%lum"
>      let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48:2:%lu:%lu:%lum"
> ```
>
> These options contain printf strings, with |printf()| (actually, its C
> equivalent hence `l` modifier) invoked with the t_ option value and
> three unsigned long integers that may have any value between 0 and 255
> (inclusive) representing red, green and blue colors respectively.

Comment: I guess it's possible to compile `st` in order to avoid this trick, but I'm not an expert about it; it could be interesting to look at it.

Comment: @ТельманБабаев : are you using `tmux`? Because my solution does not work without a tmux session, for my part

Comment: i used the method from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/St#Vim which is slightly different from your answer and now everything works both in tmux and outside of it

Comment: this will cause the opposite problem when TERM is xterm

Answer (score 1):

What is `$TERM`? `set termguicolors` only seems to work if `TERM` is `xterm*`.

I set this to make it work with other things, like `screen`/`tmux`

```
if !has('gui_running') && &term =~ '\%(screen\|tmux\)'
  let &t_8f = "\<Esc>[38;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
  let &t_8b = "\<Esc>[48;2;%lu;%lu;%lum"
endif
set termguicolors
```

This way vim uses truecolor for both `xterm*` and `screen*`/`tmux*`